# How to lazy load children routes?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I would like to configure my routing like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':angebotsNummer',
        loadChildren: './uebersicht/uebersicht.module#UebersichtModule',
        resolve: { angebotReadModel: AngebotReadModelResolver },
        children: [
            {   path: 'konditionen',
                loadChildren: './konditionen/konditionen.module#KonditionenModule',
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This would result in the child url `:angebotsNummer/konditionen`

Doing so, angular is telling me:
`Error: Invalid configuration of route ':angebotsNummer': children and loadChildren cannot be used together`

So this will not work.
How can I lazy load childrenroutes in angular, if at all?

Comment: define childroutes in the routingmodule of your lazy loaded module.

Comment: It was indeed a mistake in my url nesting.... Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you would add that configuration in the lazy module routing (Uebersicht-routing.module.ts)

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    children: [
        {   path: 'konditionen',
            loadChildren: './konditionen/konditionen.module#KonditionenModule',
        }
    ]
}]
```

And remove the children part you have:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':angebotsNummer',
        loadChildren: './uebersicht/uebersicht.module#UebersichtModule',
        resolve: { angebotReadModel: AngebotReadModelResolver }
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a

```
    loadChildren: './uebersicht/uebersicht.module#UebersichtModule',
```

then you have an inner router inside that module that does

```
component: UbersichtComponent
```

the component is the one able to carry children, the loadChildren is routing you to a nested module, but the component-loader is the one able to hold children of its own

Answer (score 0):

You can do like as below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':angebotsNummer',
        component: 'UebersichtComponent',
        resolve: { angebotReadModel: AngebotReadModelResolver },
        children: [
            {   path: 'konditionen',
                loadChildren: () => import('./+konditionen/konditionen.module').then(m => m.KonditionenModule),
            }
        ]
    }
]
```